# Syntax mistake in php

Tags: php, syntax

I don't understand, where the mistake is in this line of code.

```
$Header .= "<a href='#' onclick='ToggleView(\"Thumbnail\");return false;' title='Grid'><div class='" . 
if ($Starting_Layout = 'Thumbnail'){ echo 'active';} . " thumb-toggle-icon'></div></a>";
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: What is your error message? I could see 2-3 possible errors. 1. `if` in assignment. 2. `$Starting_Layout` is being set, not compared. 3. `$Header` not initialized.

Comment: See also: [Parse/Syntax errors: Unexpected T_IF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092318#18092318).

Comment: It's the `if ($Starting_Layout = 'Thumbnail'){ echo 'active';}` . Replace this with using short-if:  `echo ($Starting_Layout = 'Thumbnail' ? "active" : "")`

Comment: Thank you! Learn and learn.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement halfway through your output string? That doesn't look suspicious to you?